# Determining the extent of lazy evaluation

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, binary-search-tree

Given

```haskell
data BTree a = End
             | Node a (BTree a) (BTree a)
   deriving(Show,Eq,Ord)

data Msg = Msg { from :: String
               , to :: String
               , when :: Int
               , message :: String }

instance Ord Msg where
    compare a b = (when a) `compare` (when b)

instance Eq Msg where
    (==) a b = (when a) == (when b)
```

My function to count nodes (which seems off but that's aside from the question) is

```haskell
count :: (Ord a) => (BTree a) -> Int
count = sum . count'
 where
  count' :: (Ord a) => (BTree a) -> [Int] 
  count' End = []
  count' (Node _ l r) =
    [1] ++ (count' l) ++ (count' r)
```

Does `count` not evaluate the contents of the `Msg` by virtue of its value being discarded by `_`?  Perhaps a better question is, how do I know where lazy evaluation starts and ends for this sort of thing?

If the third line of `count'` was:

```haskell
count' (Node (Msg x _ _ _) l r) =
```

Can I assume that the other three fields of `Msg` were accessed/evaluated, or does lazy evaluation go that far?

Comment: No. The other fields are not evaluated. You could place a bang-pattern `((Node (Msg x !_ !_ !_) l r)` to force evaluation. Enable bang patterns by the pragma `{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}`

Comment: In pattern matching elements are evaluated only to be matched against the pattern. And thus in the case of `_` it matches anything so nothing will be evaluated.

Comment: @is7s thank you! This was the root, though not well expressed, of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The fields of a data structure are evaluated lazily by default. Since you're not using the other fields in any way, they will not be evaluated by this code. If you want to make it so that evaluating a node forces all its fields to be evaluated, you can add strictness annotations to the fields:

```
data BTree a = End
             | Node !a (BTree a) (BTree a)
   deriving(Show,Eq,Ord)

data Msg = Msg { from :: !String
               , to :: !String
               , when :: !Int
               , message :: !String }
```

Since counting the nodes forces the nodes themselves to be evaluated, this will also force the node values to be evaluated. If you only want this behavior for your one function, you can force evaluation in a more fine-grained manner using `seq`:

```
count' (Node x l r) = x `seq` ([1] ++ count' l ++ count' r)
```

or a bang pattern (requires the `BangPatterns` extension)

```
count' (Node !x l r) = [1] ++ count' l ++ count' r
```

Comment: Awesome!  I was hoping this was the case.  The point of the question was that I'm planning on using this in a long-running program and I wanted to ensure that functions like `count` didn't eat any more memory than absolutely necessary.

Comment: Strict `String` fields (or bang patterns on `String`s) will only evaluate the `String` enough to know whether it's `[]` or `_:_`:
`f (Msg _ _ _ _) = (); print (f (Msg "from" "to" 0 ('c':error "1"))) {- ok -}; print (f (Msg "from" "to" 0 (error "2"))) {- error -}`